# Working with jQuery & Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I know this is simple, but for some reason, I'm not able to process simple right now.  I'm sorry if this is a duplicate question.  I'm trying to dynamically change text in a website using just a text file, I know AJAX can pull text from a .txt file, but I've never done it before, I've only used xml files.  So my question is, how do I pull in the data from the text file and have it formatted correctly?  I'm correctly connecting to the file, but I am drawing a blank for some reason and it's not displaying the text on the page.  Again, I know this is simple, but I, for some reason, am not able to process this today.  Please help.  Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

**JavaScript/AJAX**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "text",
        url: "text.txt",
        success: function(txt){
            console.log("Working");
        }
    });
})
```

**Text**

```
Hi
```

Again, I know this is very simple to do, I'm just not registering anything right now.  So please, an outside look would help and probably jump start me.  Thanks.

Comment: Your "text" looks like HTML

Comment: oops, didn't mean to add the html tags in there.  I edited it.

Comment: You should have a valid JSON string in your text file.

Comment: I don't know anything about JSON, I've only ever used XML

Comment: @RobbyT15 if you know Javascript objects you already know almost exactly JSON (JavaScript Object Notation). JSON has just a few  constraints, see here: http://json.org/

Comment: press F12 and check your network tab on chrome see if there are any requests

Comment: I know the request is getting through, I set it up to print something to the console if there's a successful connection.  I just can't get the data from the text file to show up in the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`find` is looking throw children.
If text.txt was `<div> <p>Hi</p> </div>`, it would work correct

Comment: so, add the div tags to the text document?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do with information from file

Comment: For now I would like for it to just show up in the browser window.

Comment: Use only:
console.log(txt) - show string from file

console.log($(txt).html()) - show string inside tag p

$(txt).each(function() { console.log('Working') }) - get access for each tag element

Comment: Thank you.  Knew it was something simple.